# Tinymce 4: how to allow converting pasted content to plain text AND to normal mode

Tags: tinymce, editor, wysiwyg, wysihtml5

The new TINYMCE (version 4) allows the use of:

```
paste_as_text: true
```

The problem is that this enabled all pastes to be converted to plain text. I would to be able to do this: when the user pastes content directly to the tinymce it will always clean the content and convert it to plain text BUT if the user cliks a button a dialog appears so user can paste content in this dialog and tinymce wouldnt "touch" it, it would paste it directly to the editor.

ACTUALLY this was the default behaviour on 3.X versions, you could have a specific PASTE FROM WORD button (which actually worked for anything you wanted to paste) so you cold paste content from word and it and it would not get converted to plain text.

I see there is an external "powerful paste plugin" from tinymce but it's not free, so how can I solve this problem without having to purchase a plugin?

EDIT:

Even attaching event to the paste process I cannot change the paste_as_text dynamically like this, for example:

```
 tinymce.settings.paste_as_text = false;
```

I can execute that line in my code with no errors but it produces no effect, I continue not being able to paste content without being simplified as plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you load the `paste` plugin by default it adds two items to the Edit menu:

- Paste
- Paste as Text

...so what you want is a standard part of the `paste` plugin.  In TinyMCE 4 its exposed via the Edit Menu and not the Toolbar.

**EDIT #1:**  If you add the `pastetext` button to the toolbar that allows you to toggle the paste function between Paste as Text and regular Paste.  The button toggles the behavior that happens on a paste event.  It does not behave exactly as things did in TinyMCE 3 (the behavior you describe in your question).

**EDIT #2 - Programmatically changing this behavior**

You can use code to toggle this setting but you need a couple of different calls to get what you need.

First, you need to determine what the current "mode" is for the paste plugin. For this you can use:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.plugins.paste.clipboard.pasteFormat
```

This will (based on the current TinyMCE release of 4.6.5) return one of three values: `"html"`, `"text"`, or `undefined`.  I believe it always starts as `undefined` until you initiate the toggle once.

If you want to switch the behavior to the other mode you can do this:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceTogglePlainTextPaste');
```

Note that is is a **toggle** - so whatever it was set to it will switch to the opposite mode.  There is no exposed method call that you can use to force it to one mode or the other.

Comment: The problem is that I need to be able to "toggle that switch" using toolbar and not the menu bar, I actually hid the menu bar. Are you aware of anyway to allow PAST NORMAL and PAST PLAIN TEXT using custom buttons in the toolbar?

Comment: wow that worked really nice!!! ;) The button is great! Is there anyway I turn it on/off dynamically using the tinymce object? This solution that you provided is really great but in some cases I would like to enable/disable the paste in plain text switch using JS. I think I could fake a click in the button but I think I would prefer a better alternative like being able to set paste_as_text to false or true whenever I want.

Comment: @Samul see my second edit.  If this solves the issue can you accept the answer so others know this addressed your question?

Comment: Sure my friend, you were awesome. I have no idea how did you know about this cause I googled for hours before coming here to ask and you made a very clear answer!

Comment: @Samul I just opened the source code of the paste plugin ;-)

Comment: inspecting source code is for professionals! ;) I am still a beginner, someday I will get there and be able to understand a source code and figure things out by myself! I really appreciate your attention my friend, thanks a lot!